# Understanding Cuckoo hashing insertion

Tags: algorithm, hash

I have been trying to learn how cuckoo hashing insertion works from this pseudo code:

```
procedure insert(x)
    if lookup(x) then return
    loop MaxLoop times
        x ↔ T1[h1(x)]
        if x = ⊥ then return
        x ↔ T2[h2(x)]
        if x = ⊥ then return
    end loop
    rehash(); insert(x);
 end
```

Which was found in page 4 of this online [resource](http://cs.stanford.edu/~rishig/courses/ref/l13a.pdf). I was wondering if anyone could perhaps explain the code under `MaxLoop`?

My take on the algorithm is in these steps:

- Attempt to insert the key in the first of the two tables, using hash function `h1(x)`
- If their is a collision, attempt to insert into the second table, using `h2(x)`
- If their is a collison in the second table, insert back into first table, and kick out the previous occupying key.
- Keep repeating above steps until key is inserted. If cycle occurs, then rehash the table and start again.

I am just not understanding how these steps come into the code under `MaxLoop`?, Especially lines such as  `x ↔ T1[h1(x)]` and `x ↔ T2[h2(x)]`, which are swapping values.

If possible, Any sort of simpler version/explanation of the pseudo code would be appreciated, as it is difficult to understand this algorithm step by step from the pseudo code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, at each point the algorithm swaps the value to be inserted with a slot in a hash table. It does not check if the slot is empty, and only place the value if it is.

So a better description of the loop would be:

- Insert the key in the first of the two tables
- If that position was occupied, insert the old value into the second table.
- If that position was occupied, continue the loop.

In effect, the insertion is into a path which zig zags between the two tables, ending when an empty slot is found (or the path is too long).

The two tables must have different hash functions, because if a value had the same hash in both tables, the evicted value would go into the same slot in the other table, evicting a value which would go into the same slot in the original table, so that the maximum length of the path would be two. With different hash functions, evicted values can gi anywhere in the other table, and the typical path length can be much larger.